# A problem with getting Hibernate to work in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, repository

I wonder why I do not get this tutorial to work: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-hibernate
I am using MySQL and the example is H2, but is that relevant?

I have the repository class like this:

```
import spring.boardgame.registerboardgame.model.gameList;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface FrontGameListRepository extends JpaRepository<gameList, Long> {
     
}
```

I have the service class like this:

```
@Service
public class DataFetcher {    
    
    @Autowired
    private FrontGameListRepository frontgamelist;     
    
    public Iterable<gameList> fetchGameList(){
        return this.frontgamelist.findAll();
    }
    
}
```

And the entity class like this:

```
@Immutable
@Table(name = "gamelist")
public class gameList {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private int id;
    
    @Column
    private String navn;
    
    @Column
    private int spillinger;
    
    public gameList() {
        
    }
    
    public gameList(int nyid, String navne, int spillings) {
        this.navn = navne;
        this.id = nyid;
        this.spillinger = spillings;
    }
    
    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }   
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    
    public float getSpillinger() {
        return this.spillinger;
    }    
    public void setSpillinger(int nyf) {
        this.spillinger = nyf;
    }
    
    public void setNavn(String nynavn) {
        this.navn = nynavn;
    }
    
    public String getNavn() {
        return this.navn;
    }
    
    

}
```

Anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong? I get a crash error that the frontgamelist object in the service class is null.

Answer (score 0):

A new morning, new possibilities and I found the issue with fresh eyes. The issue was the first one pointed out in this post: https://www.moreofless.co.uk/spring-mvc-java-autowired-component-null-repository-service/

Even if this code was correct, I initiated the DataFetcher class manually in the controller, causing a null pointer exception in the next call.